# How can I have both ports 80 and 443 apache-Formula

Tags: apache, configuration, formula

I'm working on generating a vhost for my client, for now the user port is 80 as default port.
Without any update , the **vhost created** only with port 80
So I edit the files :
 **standard.tmpl**

```
 {%- set vals = {
      'interfaces': site.get('interface', '*').split(),
      'port': site.get('port', '80'),
      'port': site.get('port', '443'), # i add this line
```

**The file ports-2.4.conf.jinja**

```
{% if salt['pillar.get']('apache:sites') is mapping %}
{%- set listen_directives = [] %}
{%- for id, site in salt['pillar.get']('apache:sites').items() %}
    {%- set interfaces = site.get('interface', '*').split() %}
    {%- set port = site.get('port', 80) %}
    {%- set port = site.get('port', 443) %}# i add this line
    {%- for interface in interfaces %}
```

**user.sls**

```
apache
  user.example.com:
    - interface: '*'
      port: 80
    - interface: '*'
      port: 443
  sites:
    exclude_listen_directive: True
    interface: '*'
    port: '443'
```

After this configuration the vhoste created with only 443 port.

What I want to do is to add the 443 port to the virtualhost to be like this.

```
<Virtualhost   *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias example.com
   ServerAdmin example.com
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost   *:443>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias example.com
   ServerAdmin example.com

   SSLCertificateFile: file.pem 
   SSLCertificateKeyFile: file.key 
   SSLCertificateChainFile: file.pem 
</Virtualhost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution for now and it's to use the 80-proxyserver and the 443-proxyserver.

```
80-proxyexample.com:
  template_file: salt://apache/vhosts/redirect.tmpl
  ServerName: www.proxyexample.com
  ServerAlias: www.proxyexample.com
  RedirectSource: '/'
  RedirectTarget: 'https://www.proxyexample.com/'
  DocumentRoot: /var/www/proxy

443-proxyexample.com:
  template_file: salt://apache/vhosts/proxy.tmpl
  ServerName: www.proxyexample.com
  ServerAlias: www.proxyexample.com
  interface: '*'
  port: '443'
  DocumentRoot: /var/www/proxy
```

By this way you can have a vhost usong 80 port and the other using the 443 port